# How can I expose a single swagger-ui for two modules using SpringDoc openAPI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I'm trying to expose a single swagger-ui which documents the api of controllers exposed in two different modules.

The controllers are in different modules because I need them to be in separate containers

Here is a simplified view of my project structure:

```
.
├── rest1
│   └── java.com.foo.bar
│       └── controller
│           └── impl
│               ├── UserController.java
├── rest2
│   └── java.com.foo.bar
│       └── controller
│           └── impl
│               ├── ActionController.java
├── rest-commons
│   └── java.com.foo.bar
│       └── controller
│           └── api
│               ├── UserControllerSpec.java
│               ├── ActionControllerSpec.java
```

The ControllerSpec classes holds all the swagger annotation and the actual Controller class only have the @RestController annotation.

```
// UserControllerSpec.java
@RequestMapping("V1")
@Tag(name = "Users")
public interface UserControllerSpec {

  @Operation(summary = "Get Users")
  @ApiResponses({
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200"),
  })
  @GetMapping(value = "/users")
  ResponseEntity<UserResponsePayload> getUsers(HttpServletRequest request);
}


// ActionControllerSpec.java
@RequestMapping("V1")
@Tag(name = "Actions")
public interface ActionControllerSpec {

  @Operation(summary = "Get Actions")
  @ApiResponses({
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200"),
  })
  @GetMapping(value = "/actions")
  ResponseEntity<ActionResponsePayload> getActions(HttpServletRequest request);
}


// UserController.java
@RestController
public class UserController implements UserControllerSpec {

  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<UserResponsePayload> getUsers(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return null;
  }
}


// ActionController.java
@RestController
public class ActionController implements ActionControllerSpec {
  
  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<ActionResponsePayload> getActions(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

My end goal is to have the rest1 server expose an swagger-ui that holds both api spec.

I tried to manually scan the Spec classes as follow without success:

```
public class OpenAPIConfig {
  static {
    SpringDocUtils.getConfig().addRestControllers(UserControllerSpec.class);
  }
```

This only works if the provided class is annotated with @RestController or @Controller.

Answer (score 0):

`GroupedOpenApi` might be a solution. See https://springdoc.org/faq.html.

Based on the example you provided:

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi apiGroup() {
        String[] packages = { "java.com.foo.bar.controller.api" };
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("api").packagesToScan(packages)
                .build();
    }

}
```